# Wrong result from window.getSelection in Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to execute a command in chrome extension, I have this call:

```
chrome.commands.onCommand.addListener ( function ( command ) {
    customCommands[command]();
});
```

I have a "dictionary" object with the commands to execute:

```
var customCommands = {
    "selection" : function(data){       
        chrome.tabs.getCurrent(function (){
            var selection = window.getSelection();
            if ( selection )
            {
                alert (selection.getRangeAt(1));
            }
        });
    }
};
```

In the manifest.json I have defined a single js file, no background page. When the command is executed I receive this error:

```
Error in response to tabs.query: IndexSizeError: Failed to execute 'getRangeAt' on 'Selection': 1 is not a valid index.
```

I'm confused, what is the problem with the `window.getSelection` ?

Comment: Add the manifest into question too. Also make sure you understand [extension architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Please tell us what you _think_ `tabs.getCurrent` does. You seem to be convinced it somehow affects `window` - it does not.